# VueJS component prop only shows last JSON entry when reused

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, components

What I'm trying to do is to re-use a `vue` component with a `prop` that gets it's data from a `json` object. My problem is, that all the components contain the same data instead of the data based on the index of de `json` object.

My `json` data looks like this (snippet):

```
[
    {
        "id_department": 3,
        "code": "Test2",
        "subcode": "Test-new2",
        "fee": "1.794.405",
        "fte": "13.0",
        "fee_per_fte": "138.031",
        "details": "0",
        "indicatorChartData": [
            [
                "A",
                607990
            ],
            [
                "B",
                753637
            ],
            [
                "C",
                25321
            ]
         ]
    },
    {
        "id_department": 9,
        "code": "Test",
        "subcode": "Test-new",
        "fee": "892.571",
        "fte": "18.0",
        "fee_per_fte": "49.587",
        "details": "0",
        "indicatorChartData": [
            [
                "A",
                525829
            ],
            [
                "B",
                68512
            ],
            [
                "C",
                12660
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

My main component (which basically holds a v-for loop to fill the component that I want to re-use) looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-card :bg-variant="themeVariant.cardBG" text-variant="gray" class="card-settings" style="padding: 10px; min-height: 660px">
            <b-row>
                <b-col sm="12">
                    <span class="float-left">
                        <h5><icon name="search-plus" scale="1"/> Details</h5>
                    </span>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <hr>
            <b-row>
                <b-col sm="12">
                    <b-list-group flush>
                        <b-list-group-item v-for="i in tableData" :key="i.id_department" class="flex-column align-items-start" style="background: transparent; text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px; color: rgb(139, 154, 162)">
                            <b-row>
                                <b-col md="2">
                                    <b-button v-b-toggle="i.id_department" size="sm" :variant="themeVariant.colPrimary">
                                        Details
                                    </b-button>
                                </b-col>
                            </b-row>
                            <b-collapse :id="i.id_department">
                                <b-row>
                                    <b-col md="6">
                                        <c-srchartindicatorfee :set-chart-data="i.indicatorChartData"></c-srchartindicatorfee>
                                    </b-col>
                                </b-row>
                            </b-collapse>
                        </b-list-group-item>
                    </b-list-group>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue'
    import srchartindicatorfee from "./chartindicatorfee/srchartindicatorfee"
    export default {
        name: "srtable",
        props: {
            tableData: Array
        },
        components: {
            Icon,
            "c-srchartindicatorfee": srchartindicatorfee
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .card-settings {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

And my `c-srchartindicatorfee` component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <highcharts :options="chartIndicatorFee"></highcharts>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { chartIndicatorFee } from "./chartindicatorfee"
    export default {
        name: "srchartindicatorfee",
        props: {
            setChartData: Array
        },
        data() {
            return {
                chartIndicatorFee: chartIndicatorFee
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.chartIndicatorFee.series[0].data = this.setChartData
        },
        updated() {
            this.chartIndicatorFee.series[0].data = this.setChartData
        },
        watch: {
            setChartData: {
                handler(val) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(val));
                    this.chartIndicatorFee.series[0].data = val;
                },
                deep: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

In this last component I want to fill the `setChartData` `prop` with the `indicatorChartData array` from my `json` object.

I would expect that (since `vue` components can be re-used) every generated `c-srchartindicatorfee` component would hold it's own data (`indicatorChartData`) from the `json` via the `setChartData` `prop`, but in this case every component holds the data of the last entry within my `json` object.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: Did you try to make a copy inside your watch instead of doing `this.chartIndicatorFee.series[0].data = val;`? It could look like `this.chartIndicatorFee.series[0].data = [...val];`

Comment: I will give this a try and will let you know. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I have a new issue: I got it working but the component that I re-use is in a collapse. When I expand my first collapse, it shows me the data of the first entry in `json`. But when I also expand my second collapse, both the first chart and second chart show the data of the second `json` entry. When I expand the third collapse all the three charts contain the data of the third `json` entry, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a issue with the version of `highcharts-vue`. Updated form versions `1.2.0` to version `1.3.5`. Things work as expected now.

Thanks all!